# Finding the expectation $\mathrm{E} (1/ X)$ for a negative binomial random variable $X$

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions, lower-bounds, binomial-distribution

Suppose a random variable $X$ is distributed as $\operatorname{NB}(\mu, \theta)$, and its mass is as follows
$$ \mathrm{P}(X = y) = \binom{y + \theta - 1}{y} \left(\frac{\mu}{\mu + \theta}\right)^{y}\left(\frac{\theta}{\mu + \theta}\right)^{\theta}.$$
Does anyone know how to calculate the expectation of $1 / X$ in this kind of definition of negative binomial distribution?

If there is no explicit expression for $\mathrm{E} (1 / X)$, I wonder whether exists some lower bounds for
$$\mathrm{E} \left[ \frac{X}{(X + c)^n}\right],$$
where $c$ is some positive constant and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Thanks so much!

Comment: I believe this question would be more appropriate in https://math.stackexchange.com/. Moreover, I think the title does not represent well your final question.

Comment: Isn't $X = 0$ with positive probability?

Comment: @Kernel Thanks. My final question is finding a lower bound for $\mathrm{E} \left[ X/ (X + c)^n\right]$. The reason for my first part in the question is that: by Jensen inequality, $\mathrm{E} \left[ X / (X + c)^2\right] \geq \left[ \mathrm{E} X + 2c + c^2 \mathrm{E} (1/ X)\right]^{-1}$, then finding a upper bound for $\mathrm{E} (1/X)$ is enough.

Comment: @Kernel Oh! You said the title. Got it! Thanks so much~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica answers your second question for concrete values of $n$ (e.g. $n=3$) by

```
Mean[TransformedDistribution[X/(c + X)^3, X \[Distributed] NegativeBinomialDistribution[\[Mu], \[Theta]],Assumptions->c>0]]
```

$$-\frac{(\theta -1) \mu  \theta ^{\mu } \, _4F_3(c+1,c+1,c+1,\mu +1;c+2,c+2,c+2;1-\theta )}{(c+1)^3} $$

Comment: Thanks. But it seems that it is also involved to find a lower bound of the expectation from this formula.